# Copyright of name in movies

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, copyright, bright

There are many movies that take original Lord of the Rings characters. Such as human, orcs, and elves.  One of these movies is Bright with Will Smith

To make such movie, do they need copy right approval from anyone? Or can anyone use any character they want without permission

Would it be ok if they used Harry Potter's characters?

Comment: The question only makes sense if you're not talking about individual characters but fantasy races. But in that case, why do you include "human"?

Comment: @JollyJoker Why wouldn't, for example, Bilbo Baggins make sense? That's also an originally created character, noted by the answer.

Comment: @JackJohansson  But there are no other movies using Bilbo Baggins

Comment: @JollyJoker I said the copyright issue makes sense, not that there's a movie with  Bilbo in it. That was an example though.

Comment: @JackJohansson: I assume your point is about "hobbit" and not "Bilbo Baggins" (in which case it is a valid point), but your comment does not make that clear.

Comment: I often see TradeMarks added to such names, like here: https://www.mobygames.com/images/covers/l/67936-harry-potter-and-the-sorcerer-s-stone-playstation-back-cover.jpg

Comment: You can't copyright an **archetype**. And AFAIK, *Bright* didn't use any **proper nouns** that the Tolkien estate holds a copyright over.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For a character to be protected by copyright, it must be an original creation. Tolkien never had a copyright on elves or orcs, because both of those creatures existed in literature prior to *The Lord of the Rings*. On the other hand, Hobbits were an original creation, so the use of a Hobbit character would require a license from the Tolkien estate. That's why *Dungeons and Dragons*, for example, refers to Hobbit-like creatures as "Halflings".

Extending that to Harry Potter, we see a similar mix of established and original characters and creatures. Anyone can tell a story with a basilisk, or a centaur, or a hippogriff, because these creatures are all derived from classical antiquity. On the other hand, I could not include a Death-Eater or a Horcrux in a new work, as those would be protected by copyright.

Comment: To clarify "horcrux" as a *name* might be a problem but not as a concept. It's been around for a long while - an object that prevents a magician from dying by housing (part of) their soul. A common example is a lich's phylactery from D&D but it's far older than that - many folk tales have a similar object. One of the more well known folk characters is Koschei the Deathless from Russian folklore - he famously had his soul in a needle nested in several elusive animals that one had to hunt.

Comment: @vlaz Would one of the more well known examples of a "horcrux" type item be [The Picture Of Dorian Grey?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Picture_of_Dorian_Gray)

Comment: @Philbo I suppose you could call it that. Although normally they are associated with magicians who used their magic to create them, as opposed to "normal" people who attained an item making them immortal. But then again, non-magicians coming into posession such an object is not uncommon, either.

Comment: The One Ring is basically a horcrux

Comment: What if something was an explicit reference to the original thing?  Like if you had a science fiction TV show where there was a space station named "Minas Tirith", and it's explicitly noted that it's named after the Tolkien creation?

Comment: Is there any statutory or regulatory basis for attaching copyright protection to mere names?  If a story features a character named Gandalf, there may be a clear intention to benefit from readers' knowledge of that character as expressed in another work, but if the new story avoids saying anything that was said in the old story, what exactly would the new story be "copying"?  What if the new story had a character named "Grandal" who had been forced to change his name in the aftermath of some events that had resulted in an evil lord's ring being thrown into a fiery fissure?

Comment: Tolkien didn't invent the name Gandalf which is an old Germanic one.  Some people have heard of Castle Gandolfo in Italy or Philadelphia newswoman Cathy Gandolfo.  My favorite Gandalf was a king of the small kingdom of Alfheimr, a name that means "Elf Home".

Comment: Pretty full list of horcruxes: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SoulJar

Comment: FYI: The makers Dungeons and Dragons were legally allowed to use the term 'Hobbit' in the game (ie. it was determined that Tolkien's copyright didn't prevent it), but the designers (Gygax in particular) decided against. See [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/116285/23196).

Answer (score 4):

Names and titles are not protected by US copyright. See [Circular 1, Copyright Basics](https://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ01.pdf).

You may be thinking of trademarks; I suggest searching [TESS](https://www.uspto.gov/trademark) to find out what protections exist for a given name. If you want to make commercial use of an existing character you should definitely get a lawyer.